# Search view and tabLayout does not work properly for one tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, search, android-tablelayout

I have a search view and in its bottom side, there are two tabs and below them there is a `Viewpager` and all works connected. I also have a text change listener for search view and in it, I am getting data from server and put it `RecyclerView` which are in fragments.

```
private void setSearch() {
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (!newText.isEmpty()) {
                ManagerAll.getInstance().fetchFiltereds(newText).enqueue(new Callback<List<a>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<a>> call, Response<List<a>> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), response.body(), getFragmentManager());
                            list.setAdapter(adapter );
                            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                            list.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<a>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I put this method (above) to both fragment that are laying inside viewPager. Almost everything works fine. All data according to text flows to recycler view but this data only comes to second tab. In first tab's fragment, there is no data. SearchView works for both fragment but only second fragment gets filled by data. First one is just empty even though I change text in search view.

Comment: Is the adapter same for both the tabs recyclerview? Please mention my name with @ and my name will pop up to get my attention here again.

Comment: I put the method I gave above in two different classes. FragmentA and FragmentB. FragmentB's onTextChange listener overrides fragmentA's listener and search function does not work for fragmentA but does for fragmentB @nimi0112. What do you mean by adapter? These includes recycler view but I dont think it is related.